# "Parent context is required for this entity type" when querying for Contact Interactions on xConnect OData

Tags: xconnect, odata

We are using `Microsoft Power BI` to mine into `xConnect OData`. We are interested, among other things, in the Interactions of our contacts. However, Power BI generates requests that cannot be fulfilled by xConnect OData, such as this one:

`GET https://[xconnect-search-host]/odata/Contacts([contact-id])/Identifiers`

This is a valid OData query, but xConnect fails with this error message:

```
{
  "ClassName": "System.InvalidOperationException",
  "Message": "Parent context is required for this entity type",
  "Data": null,
  "InnerException": null,
  "HelpURL": null,
  "StackTraceString": "   at Sitecore.XConnect.Web.Infrastructure.Serialization.Newtonsoft.Context.ContextProvider.GetContext(IEdmType type, SelectExpand selectExpand, String entitySetName)\r\n   at Sitecore.XConnect.Web.Infrastructure.Serialization.Newtonsoft.ODataJsonSerializer.Serialize(JsonWriter writer, Object value, ODataSerializationOptions options)\r\n   at Sitecore.XConnect.Web.Infrastructure.Serialization.Newtonsoft.ODataJsonSerializer.Serialize(TextWriter writer, Object value, ODataSerializationOptions options)\r\n   at Sitecore.XConnect.Web.Infrastructure.Serialization.Newtonsoft.ODataFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync[TValue](TValue value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)",
  "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
  "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
  "ExceptionMethod": "8\nGetContext\nSitecore.XConnect.Web, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null\nSitecore.XConnect.Web.Infrastructure.Serialization.Newtonsoft.Context.ContextProvider\nSitecore.XConnect.Web.Infrastructure.Serialization.Newtonsoft.Context.ContextEntry GetContext(Microsoft.OData.Edm.IEdmType, Sitecore.XConnect.Web.Infrastructure.Serialization.Newtonsoft.SelectExpand, System.String)",
  "HResult": -2146233079,
  "Source": "Sitecore.XConnect.Web",
  "WatsonBuckets": null
}
```

Interestingly, the closely related query resolves correctly:

`GET https://[xconnect-search-host]/odata/Contacts([contact-id])?$expand=Interactions`

Is this a known error in Sitecore? Is there a workaround or hotfix that could resolve it?

Keep in mind that we cannot control the requests that are generated by Power BI and that they are valid OData 4 requests anyway, which xConnect claims to support.

We are using `Sitecore 9 update 2 (version 9.0.2)`.